# Optimización de código - Quantstrat R

Tags: r, optimización

Tengo un problema para optimizar mi código, ya que de momento es funcional pero muy básico. La situación es esta:

```
# 2) Establecer los activos que contemplados en el estudio ####
    stks <- c("AAPL","MSFT","TSLA","FB", "LMT", "AMZN", "NVDA")

# 3) Obtener los datos ####
getSymbols(stks, 
           from = "2020-01-01",
           to = "2020-06-26", #Sys.Date()
           src = "yahoo",
           adjust = TRUE)
```

Hasta ahí todo correcto, el problema es cuando quiero obtener los retornos

```
# 4) Obtener los rendimientos de los activos ####


aapl_returns <- Return.calculate(Cl(AAPL))
aapl_returns <- aapl_returns[(-1),] #elimina el NA inicial

msft_returns <- Return.calculate(Cl(MSFT))
msft_returns <- msft_returns[(-1),] #elimina el NA inicial

tsla_returns <- Return.calculate(Cl(TSLA))
tsla_returns <- tsla_returns[(-1),] #elimina el NA inicial

fb_returns <- Return.calculate(Cl(FB))
fb_returns <- fb_returns[(-1),] #elimina el NA inicial

lmt_returns <- Return.calculate(Cl(LMT))
lmt_returns <- lmt_returns[(-1),] #elimina el NA inicial

amzn_returns <- Return.calculate(Cl(AMZN))
amzn_returns <- amzn_returns[(-1),] #elimina el NA inicial

nvda_returns <- Return.calculate(Cl(NVDA))
nvda_returns <- nvda_returns[(-1),] #elimina el NA inicial
```

Esta parte es la que no logro optimizar ya que si trato de meter o quitar una acción debo proceder a borrar o agregar mas linea de código. al final trate de hacer algo asi, pero no logro tener éxito para después agregarle la función de `Return.calculate()`

```
returns <- lapply(stks,paste0,stks[0],"_returns")
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido Jorge a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sin duda usar `lapply` simplifica mucho y sobre todo hace más genérica la solución, el tema es construir una función que reciba un "stock" y termine retornando la serie de tiempo que le corresponde. Algo como esto:

```
rcalc <- function(x) {
  e <- environment()
  ret <- Return.calculate(Cl(get(x, envir=parent.env(e))))
  ret[-1,]
}
```

Finalmente, la puedes usar así:

```
names(stks) <- stks # Esto para que la lista tenga los nombres
returns <- lapply(stks, rcalc)

# Y ahora accedemos fácilmente:
returns$AAPL
returns$MSFT
returns$TSLA
```

Si quieres un `data.frame` único hay que hacer algunos cambios ya que el retorno en cada caso es un `xts`:

```
rcalc <- function(x) {
  e <- environment()
  ret <- Return.calculate(Cl(get(x, envir= parent.env(e))))[-1,]
  ret = data.frame(date=index(ret), coredata(ret))
  setNames(cbind(x, ret), c("fecha", "stock", "valor"))
}
```

Ahora en vez de retornar un `xts` retornamos un `data.frame` clásico, finalmente para "unir" todo podemos hacer:

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(stks, rcalc))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, por la respuesta, me ayudo mucho. Solo una pregunta mas, ¿se podría obtener los datos, unicamente en un data set?. Traté con `p <- dplyr::data_frame(as.data.frame(paste0("returns$",stks)))` , y con `p <- dplyr::data_frame(returns$AAPL,returns$MSFT)` funciona pero de nuevo, no es eficiente. Gracias.

Comment: El tema es que el retorno es un xts y no un data.frame, debes convertirlos primero, verifica mi última edición